# How to check if Zend select returns a result or not

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

In Zend framework, how do I check if `zend_db_select` returns a result or not?

```
$result = $this->fetchAll();
```

is there a better way rather than using:

```
if(count($result) != 0){
    //result found!
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you show here?

Comment: I'm finding a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$rows = $this->fetchAll();
return (!empty($rows)) ? $rows : null;
```

Answer (score 6):

I like to use the classic:

```
   //most of these queries return either an object (Rowset or Row) or FALSE 
   if (!$result){
        //do some stuff
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found this way and works fine for me :

```
if($result->count() > 0) {
    //Do something
}
```

Thanks to [Åsmund](http://www.herikstad.net/2010/10/check-if-zenddbtablerowset-is-empty.html) !

Answer (score 1):

The method return NULL, not FALSE. Check for this value using a if condition.